# Issues with Salesforce Data entry in journey for Person Account

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, salesforce-data-mask

I've created a journey with a Salesforce Data entry source. Its a very simple configuration. I look for ContactId from contact and my entry criteria is just a field con "PROMO" from Contact, which is a check field, is created or updated to TRUE.

I must mention that in my service cloud we have Business Accounts and Person Accounts.

After activation, when I test it, I modify this field in a business account and the contact enters correctly into the journey.
But it doesn't happen so for the person account.

I do not understand why I can't get any person account to entre salesforce data journeys.

Does it have to do with a configuration settings in the connector?

I understand that a person account is an account and a contact in the same slot. But the field that I'm looking at is a contact based field that both users have.

Can anyone please help me?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this behavior happens because the Salesforce data entry source in Journey Builder evaluates a trigger based on the main object, not "Who" they will inject into.

If you look at the Journey entry event board on the left side, you will see that the evaluating object is `Contact` (in your case). So the attributes for the data source will be the attributes from Contact object, while if the object is `Account` (for Person Account), it will have the different attribute name - suffix with `__pc` instead.

So to evaluate both contact (not person account) and contact is person account. You would need to create a separate journey where the object is `Account` with the entry criteria is now `PROMO = true` which is actually `PROMO__pc = true`.